# django always giving same default values

Tags: django, model, default

I have my payment_id generated based on UTC time and append 4 random characters to it. But when i call the function, the utc_now() and random_string(4) seems like they were only executed once.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
  PAYMENT_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('P','Pending'),
    ('A','Paid'),
    ('C','Canceled'),
  )
  PAYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('E','Electrician'),
    ('S','Salesman'),
  )
  def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.payment_id,str(self.record_time),self.get_payment_type_display(),self.payment_status)

  led_gu5_3_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
  led_gu10_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
  cfl_bc_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
  cfl_es_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
  cfl_sbc_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
  cfl_ses_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
  initial = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
  record_time = models.DateTimeField(default=utc_now(),editable=False)
  payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=utc_now().strftime('%y%m%d')+random_string(4),editable=False)
  payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=PAYMENT_STATUS_CHOICES,default='P')
  payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=PAYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Here goes the output when I test it in terminal:

```
>>> from payment_sys.models import *
>>> payments = [Payment(led_gu5_3_price = 0, led_gu10_price=0,cfl_bc_price = 0, cfl_es_price=0,cfl_sbc_price = 0,cfl_ses_price = 0,initial = 0,payment_type ='E') for i in xrange(3)]
>>> payments
[<Payment: 140801ZKGI 2014-08-01 16:32:36.158811+00:00 Electrician P>, <Payment: 140801ZKGI 2014-08-01 16:32:36.158811+00:00 Electrician P>, <Payment: 140801ZKGI 2014-08-01 16:32:36.158811+00:00 Electrician P>]
```

As can be seen, time are the same, and the random strings are the same as well. I want the utc_now() and random_string(4) to be executed every time when I create a new Payment object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a callable, not a value.

```
def default_payment_id():
    return utc_now().strftime('%y%m%d')+random_string(4)

payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=default_payment_id)
```

Note the lack of calling parentheses in the default: this way Django knows to call it on instantiation, not at import time.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default
I just found the answer here as well.

Comment: But is it a good idea to make this method a static method of the class Payment?